# Running a MinGW g++ compiled program in AppContainer and throws ERROR_ILLEGAL_DLL_RELOCATION

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to running a g++ complied program in AppContainer, but it throws a last error 623.

MSDN explains this code as **ERROR_ILLEGAL_DLL_RELOCATION**

> {Illegal System DLL Relocation} The system DLL %hs was relocated in
>   memory. The application will not run properly. The relocation occurred
>   because the DLL %hs occupied an address range reserved for Windows
>   system DLLs. The vendor supplying the DLL should be contacted for a
>   new DLL.

I think the program running in AppContainer has no access to read the memory DLL, but the MSVC compiled program works fine.

Like the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Its works fine with directly using `CreateProcess()`, but returned 623 error in the AppContainer.

g++ didn't add extra compile directives, it is   g++ -g {source file} -o {target file}.exe

Requirement: solve the 623 error.

Reference: [AppContainer](https://github.com/MalwareTech/AppContainerSandbox)

g++ version: MinGW 8.2.0-4

MSVC version: 14.22.27905

Windows SDK: 10.0.17134.0

Comment: I suspect it's because the executable is missing the relocation table. If so, try to add `-Wl,--export-all-symbols` to your g++ command.

Comment: It worked! I am really excited now because this problem has been bothering me for almost half a year! I don't know how to express my gratitude!